# Simple Vue app shows just blank pages (webpack-dev-server)

Tags: vue.js, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

Starting my first Vue app, but after adding some routes, I can't seem to get any output in the browser. Before the routing, I was able to see a simple static string. I have a suspicion the problem lies in the Webpack (v4) config, but I can't find the cause after checking several different examples.

[image]

**config/index.js**

```
'use strict';

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

const resolve = (dir) => {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir);
};

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    filename: 'build.js',
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, '../dist'),
    historyApiFallback: true,
    watchContentBase: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue'],
    alias: {
      '@': resolve('src'),
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: ['vue-loader', 'vue-style-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.css/,
        use: 'css-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        cache: true,
        parallel: true,
        uglifyOptions: {
          compress: true,
          ecma: 8,
          mangle: true
        },
        sourceMap: true,
      })
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true,
    }),
  ]
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
    }),
  ]);
};
```

**src/router/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import Hello from '@/views/HelloPage';
import About from '@/views/AboutPage';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Hello',
      component: Hello,
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'About',
      component: About,
    }
  ]
});
```

**src/views/AboutPage.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <h1>About</h1>
    <p>What is this about?</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'About',
}
</script>
```

**src/views/HelloPage.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p>Hi there. {{ msg }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'hello',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'This is a test',
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
p {
  color: silver;
}
</style>
```

**src/App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-link to="/hello">Hello</router-link>
    <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App'
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: black;
}
</style>
```

**src/main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App />',
  components: { App },
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Paste 4.0</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**The commands I use**

build: `NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode production --config config/index.js`
start: `webpack-dev-server --mode development --config config/index.js --open`

I don't get any errors or warnings from either command, and no messages in the browser console (Chrome, Firefox) either. All pages remain blank, and I don't get a `Cannot GET /about` message when opening it manually. Even non-existing routes do not get that message. The contents in the browser inspector are:

**Update:**
Now the `<script>` tag appears and there is some function appearing, but still, the page is empty and no errors appear. The file `build.js` is available, as I can access it directly via localhost:8080/build.js
[image]

The output of the start command (the two components are **missing** from this):

```
> webpack-dev-server --mode development --config config/index.js --open

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /dist/
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /index.html
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Hash: 766e36fda2265e10c49a
Version: webpack 4.15.1
Time: 3621ms
Built at: 07/11/2018 12:04:44 PM
     Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
  build.js    660 KiB    main  [emitted]  main
index.html  209 bytes          [emitted]  
Entrypoint main = build.js
[./node_modules/ansi-html/index.js] 4.16 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/html-entities/index.js] 231 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js] 7.68 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js] 161 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/url/url.js] 22.8 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js] 207 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:8080] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 7.75 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.58 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.05 KiB {main} [built]
[0] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/main.js 40 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/hot sync ^\.\/log$] (webpack)/hot sync nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/hot/emitter.js] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 77 bytes {main} [built]
[./src/App.vue] 401 bytes {main} [built]
[./src/main.js] 168 bytes {main} [built]
[./src/router/index.js] 374 bytes {main} [built]
    + 28 hidden modules
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = index.html
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./index.html] 351 bytes {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js] 527 KiB {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 489 bytes {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built]
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

Whereas in the build output, the two components **do** exist:

```
> NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode production --config config/index.js

Hash: f63c24ae8589460a1b7c
Version: webpack 4.15.1
Time: 2790ms
Built at: 07/11/2018 12:00:51 PM
     Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
  build.js   90.9 KiB       0  [emitted]  main
index.html  209 bytes          [emitted]  
 [0] ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./src/views/AboutPage.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css 162 bytes {0} [built]
 [1] ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./src/views/HelloPage.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css 162 bytes {0} [built]
 [2] ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css 159 bytes {0} [built]
 [5] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 489 bytes {0} [built]
 [6] ./src/main.js + 6 modules 68.3 KiB {0} [built]
     | ./src/main.js 168 bytes [built]
     | ./src/App.vue 360 bytes [built]
     | ./src/router/index.js 374 bytes [built]
     | ./src/views/HelloPage.vue 369 bytes [built]
     | ./src/views/AboutPage.vue 369 bytes [built]
     |     + 2 hidden modules
 [7] ./src/views/AboutPage.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css 570 bytes {0} [built]
 [8] ./src/views/HelloPage.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css 570 bytes {0} [built]
 [9] ./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css 534 bytes {0} [built]
[13] multi ./src/main.js 28 bytes {0} [built]
    + 5 hidden modules
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    [0] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built]
    [1] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 489 bytes {0} [built]
    [3] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./index.html 351 bytes {0} [built]
        + 1 hidden module
```

Comment: It seems that Webpack does not even see the two view components, as for example the string ``Hi there`` does not exist in the final ``dist/build.js``, even though it exists in ``src/views/HelloPage.vue``. But strangely, that file does exist in the build log.

Comment: Okay, I think it is related to the webpack-dev-server. When I run the build, the two components appear, but when I run the dev-server, those two files do not exist in the build output.

Comment: There is probably something wrong happening with the `html-webpack-plugin`. The HTML page source code that you show from your browser inspector does not even include the `<script>` tag to load your app script.

Comment: Hmm, I got the ``<script>`` to appear after some tuning, but the page remains blank. I have updated the post with the latest file contents.

Comment: After some more debugging and adjusting various things, I got it working, but even after reverting those changes one by one, I still don't have an explanation for why it didn't work originally and hence what was the cause. Let's see if I can pinpoint the cause.

Answer (score -1):

I think the script section from the App.vue should extend the Vue component.

Something like:

```
<script>
import Vue from "vue";      // First import Vue
export default Vue.extend({ // Then extend it creating your component
  name: 'App'
});
</script>
```

Same goes for the other .vue pages...

Comment: Hmm, the standard Vue package doesn't use that, but I tried anyway. No luck.

Comment: When you do ``npm install vue-cli && vue init webpack test-app``, it creates an App.vue with this: ``<script>export default { name: 'App' }</script>``, so I don't think it's about the ``extend()``

Comment: @tanathos [Vue SFC](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html)'s are expected to export directly the [component options](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data), as explained in [`vue-loader`'s SFC spec](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/spec.html#script). Although exporting the `Vue.extend()` is also supported.